# display My data table values in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need do this in My Laravel app I have following tables.collaborators, 
[image]

and project table is
[image]

in My app when some user is logged they can create new projects and save them in project table and in one project they can add new collaborators with the project. it saved with collaborators table. users current projects showing in the index.blade.php file. I need to show projects link if that logged user collaborator to another projects.
here is My code showing current projects of the user in My ProjectController.php

```
    public function index(){

  $projects = Project::personal()->get();// this show existing projects 

 //I need show collaborator projects here

  return view('projects.index')->withProject($projects);}
```

can you help me.....